# ¿Tengo que traducir el texto de los errores?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

A menudo, cuando publico una pregunta, al menos traduzco el error en el título de la pregunta. No he hecho una prueba A/B para ver si es más efectivo pero siempre me lo he preguntado:

- cuál es la mejor práctica
- ¿cuál es la práctica más eficaz?

Si la primera pregunta puede responderse conjuntamente, imagino que la segunda requiere un poco de conocimiento de la NLP y de cómo utilizar da https://data.stackexchange.com/es/

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' si, es duplicada.. pero estaria bueno 6 años despues, volver a tener esta discusion, sobre todo porque en las respuestas se nota que seguimos en la misma tonica....

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' si.. seguro.. pero en este caso, las respuestas ya están bien, y yo estoy de acuerdo con ellas...

Answer (score 13):

La Informática se habla en inglés.

En la traducción al castellano pierdes precisión. Es aceptable cuando los textos van dirigidos a usuarios finales, donde el énfasis está en facilitar la comprensión.

Nosotros, los del área IT, necesitamos precisión. No podemos contar con una traducción *canónica*; tal cosa no existe. Distintas personas producen distintas traducciones.

El problema es que tenemos más términos técnicos distintos en inglés que en castellano. Imposible hacer un mapeo uno a uno; hay que recurrir a frases explicativas o inventar traducciones que nadie más maneja.

¿Cómo traduces *buffer*? "Memoria tampón" trae asociaciones inapropiadas; "memoria intermedia" puede confundirse con *cache*, etc.

Mi favorita: *registro*. En el mensaje de error (Windows en castellano) dice *registro*. ¿A qué se refiere? Alternativas: Windows Registry, machine register, log.

Mi política es mantener los textos tal cual se escribieron, digitaron o imprimieron. Hay que ser veraz a la fuente.

Comment: La informática no se habla en ningún idioma pues no es un lenguaje si no una disciplina profesional. Como disciplina profesional sus profesionales hablan diferentes idiomas y entre ellos el inglés es de los más hablados. Pero el Español es el segundo idioma con más hablantes nativos del mundo y merece tener su sitio en la programación. Por cierto: [búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAfer_de_datos).

Answer (score 13):

Personalmente preferiría que **no** se intentase traducir el error ​porque generalmente eso me obliga a *des-traducirlo* al intentar responder.

Me explico: la mayoría del código fuente de las librerías más populares, sin importar el lenguaje, tiene los comentarios en inglés y los mensajes de error en inglés. Hay veces que los desarrolladores se esfuerzan en localizar los mensajes de error, por lo que las trazas de error aparecen en el idioma definido por el usuario para el sistema operativo donde se están ejecutando.

Por tanto, si busco en la red un mensaje de error tal cual lo ha mostrado la ejecución, es fácil que encuentre

- respuestas en SO en inglés que solucionan el problema
- El código fuente de la librería que se está *quejando*, con lo que puedo intentar averiguar el origen del problema.
- Un FAQ o un *issue* en Github u otro repositorio donde alguien ha abierto un incidente a los desarrolladores porque se han encontrado con el mismo problema.

Además, si el usuario no sabe inglés, lo más seguro es que tenga su PC configurado en español, con lo que un error en inglés indica que ese software no tiene i18n para los mensajes de error. Todo esto significa que:

- El usuario no va a ser capaz de traducir el texto del error.
- El usuario va a intentar copiar y pegar el texto del error en Google, con lo que encontrará una pregunta/respuesta si ese texto no está traducido "manualmente".
- Cualquier traducción mal hecha puede desviarnos al traducir: Por ejemplo, en Java existen los arrays, la clase ArrayList y la clase Vector. Si alquien intentase traducir array por vector o arreglo, podría crear incertidumbres.

Por tanto, en alguna ocasión me ha tocado "traducir de nuevo" al inglés para intentar comprender el error o deshacer una mala traducción que pueda haber confundido al OP

Answer (score 2):

#### ¿Cuál es la mejor práctica?

La mejor práctica es aquella que ayude a más gente. Si dispones del texto de error en varios idiomas publica dicho error en todos los idiomas que tengas disponibles, esto hará que tu pregunta aparezca en las búsquedas de esos idiomas llegando a más gente.

#### ¿Cuál es la práctica más eficaz?

La más eficaz es no olvidar el código de error. Generalmente los errores de compilación o ejecución vienen acompañados de un código que es independiente del idioma con que el error se redacte. Por poner un ejemplo: no necesitamos mucho esfuerzo para saber lo que es un error 404 pero tal vez nos cueste más identificar un error "*Not Found*" o "*No encontrado*".

Answer (score 2):

El error debe ponerse como lo muestra el software que está generándolo. Traducirlo puede hacer difícil que otros lo repliquen o que se puedan encontrar soluciones en otro lugar (porque una búsqueda sobre un mensaje traducido no dará ningún resultado)